# Crop local image file

Tags: php, javascript, html

I got a form that allow user to upload image and crop it 
I already figured out the flow of it

1.User upload the image
2.Server process it and send back to the browser
3.User crop it and send to the server
4.Server process and save it

Is there any other way to achieve this?
Perhaps using javascript to load the image and then crop it then after that send to server to process it.
Is there a way?

**Edited**
Im looking to avoid sending those image to server to process it.
Probably load the file using FileReader..
I have no luck on googling it

Comment: You might want to check out this link... http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FileReader` + `Canvas` to read the local file and then crop it without sending it to the server.

Here's a demo showing how to do that.

```
<form><input type="file" id=f></form>
<canvas id=c width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
var f = document.getElementById('f');
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
f.onchange = function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);
          var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
          //alert(pngUrl); // send this url to server to save the image
        }
        img.src = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
</script>
```

What you still need to do is use the jquery jcrop plugin in order to let the user select the cropping area because in this demo I just hard coded a crop of the top left 100x100 pixels.

It looks like you'll want to use [jcrops onSelect](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Event_Handlers) event to get the origin + width + height of the cropping area, and feed those values into `context.drawImage`

hopefully you can handle the rest, good luck

Comment: this is what i want, thx u so much, sure not probem sir,  i ll upvote it

Answer (score 1):

For this, [I'd use jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html). Make sure you have access to ImageMagick and/or GD on your system--you'll most likely need that for processing.

EDIT (Oct 2, 2021) - The original link/library looks to be abandoned. I haven't tried this yet but it looks like it will work: https://jcrop.com/

Comment: so basically i need to send to the server to process it first and then send back to browser and use jcrop to allow user to crop it right?..what im looking is, is there a way to load the image using javascript itself and then crop it

Comment: well, the server part will come into play after you make your crop selection. i would check out the examples here http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

Comment: yes that what i want, after user crop it first then send to server rather than send the uploaded image without crop it first...still, thx for ur suggestion

Comment: link looks broken

Comment: Thanks @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier, I updated the answer